# Why are Vedas not called Drushya rather than Shruti?

Tags: vedas

Vedas are called shruti. But they are seen by Rishis, called DrushTAras. Since the Rishis saw the Vedas in some form, then Vedas should be called Drushya instead of shruti. Or the Rishis have to be called ShrOtRu. Why is not that usage in vogue?

Comment: I think the issue is simply that the Vedas are neither seen nor heard.  They're perceived by some spiritual sense, and we use both seeing and hearing as metaphors for that spiritual sense.

Answer (score 2):

Name shruti came from user's perspective not from drustara's perspective.
As Shurti mean one which is learned only though listening and repeating from Guru.While Smriti by reading from book/something written.

see below sloka on rules for learning Veda's. One of them is "Likitapaathakaa:" chanting mantras by reading from book!.

geetI, shIGrI, shira:kaMpi, tathaa liKitapaaThaka: |
anarthajnO,alpakaMThashcha paDEtE paaThakaadhamaa:

Comment: Smriti doesn't have anything to do with writing.  It just means that which is remembered.  Smriti texts were passed down by oral tradition long before they were committed to writing.  The Shruti/Smriti distinction has nothing to do with oral tradition vs. written manuscripts.  Both Shruti and Smriti were originally passed down by oral tradition, the difference is that Shruti texts like the Vedas are Apaurusheya or without a human author, whereas Smriti texts are of human origin and they constitute the received wisdom of a guru parampara.

Comment: Also, you should mention where that Shloka comes from, and you should provide a translation of it.

Answer (score 2):

Actually the Sloka you have quoted "geetI, shIGrI, shira:kaMpi, tathaa liKitapaaThaka: | anarthajnO,alpakanThashcha paDEtE paaThakaadhamaa:" actually translates to what all is considered Adhamam(last word of sloka) which is the least favored. There are three levels, Uttamam, Madhyamam and Adhamam. Vedas are not supposed to be sung (Geeti) , or the speed shouldn't be increased for our comfort (Sheegri), should notbe Shaking the head while chanting (Shirakampi) and finally should not be written down and recited ( Likitha Pataka). It should be heard and then recited, hence its called Shruti.

Comment: If you want to comment on an answer, please wait for rep of 50.